# How to get access to properties in child component in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular8

I create dynamically a child component `this.data.component` using `resolveComponentFactory`:

```
export class MyDialogComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild("target", { static: true , read: ViewContainerRef}) viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;

  componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.data.component);
    this.componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.componentRef) {
      this.componentRef.destroy();
    }
  }
}
```

Child component looks:

```
@Component({
  selector: "simple-dict-word-dialog",
  templateUrl: "./dictionarySimpleWord-dialog.component.html"
})
export class DictionarySimpleDialogComponent {

}
```

How to get access in child component to object `this.data`?

I tried this:

```
const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.data.component);
this.componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
this.componentRef.instance.type = "ok";
this.componentRef.instance.mode = {id: 1};
```

And my child component is:

```
export class DictionarySimpleDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() model: ClassificatorOrganizations;
  @Input() type: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.type);
    console.log(this.model);
  }
}
```

So, I can not get:

```
console.log(this.type);
console.log(this.model);
```

They are empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ComponentRef` has the `instance` property that is your child component instance. You can pass your data to it as provided in [Angular 2 dynamically add component instance into container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37853291/angular-2-dynamically-add-component-instance-into-container).

Comment: How to close dialog in parentComponent?